# Looping over attributes vector to produce combined graphs

Tags: r, graph, attr, effects

Here is some code that tries to compute the marginal effects of each of the predictors in a model (using the [effects](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/) package) and then plot the results. To do this, I am looping over the `"term.labels"` attribute of the `glm` `terms` object).

```
library(DAAG)
library(effects)

formula = pres.abs ~ altitude + distance + NoOfPools + NoOfSites + avrain + meanmin + meanmax
summary(logitFrogs <- glm(formula = formula, data = frogs, family = binomial(link = "logit")))


par(mfrow = c(4, 2))
for (predictorName in attr(logitFrogs$terms, "term.labels")) {
    print(predictorName)
    effLogitFrogs <- effect(predictorName, logitFrogs)
    plot(effLogitFrogs)
}
```

This produces no picture at all. On the other hand, explicitly stating the predictor names does work:

```
effLogitFrogs <- effect("distance", logitFrogs)
plot(effLogitFrogs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the issue is one of plotting from a for-loop.  If you google it, you'll find lots of info, but I have yet to see a good solution. Have a look at `?x11()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you call function `plot()`, actually it calls function `plot.eff()` and it is lattice plot and so `par()` argument is ignored. One solution is to use function `allEffects()` and then `plot()`. This will call function `plot.efflist()`. With this function you do not need for loop because all plots are made automatically.

```
effLogitFrogs <- allEffects(predictorName, logitFrogs)
plot(effLogitFrogs)
```

### EDIT - solution with for loop

There is "ugly" solution to use with `for()` loop. For this we need also package `grid`. First, make as variables number of rows and columns (now it works only with 1 or 2 columns). Then `grid.newpage()` and `pushViewport()` set graphical window.

Predictor names are stored in vector outside the loop. Using functions `pushViewport()` and `popViewport()` all plots are put in the same graphical window.

```
  library(lattice)
  library(grid)

  n.col=2
  n.row= 4 
  grid.newpage()      
  pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(n.row,n.col)))

  predictorName <- attr(logitFrogs$terms, "term.labels")

  for (i in 1:length(predictorName)) {
    print(predictorName[i])
    effLogitFrogs <- effect(predictorName[i], logitFrogs)
    pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col=ceiling(i/n.row), layout.pos.row=ifelse(i-n.row<=0,i,i-n.row)))
    p<-plot(effLogitFrogs)
    print(p,newpage=FALSE)
    popViewport(1)
  }
```

Comment: even allEffects call lattice and is not ignored. It is just a print problem.

Comment: I would have preferred to use a loop solution (as in @agstudy 's reply), and I did consider using the `allEffects` function before, but I did not realise the dificulties with plotting inside a loop. I think `allEffects` is easiest in this case.

Answer (score 1):

add `print` to your loop resolve the problem.

```
 print(plot(effLogitFrogs))
```

`plot` call `plot.eff` , which create the plot without printing it.

`allEffects` generete an object of type `eff.list`. When we try to plot this object, its calls  `plot.efflist` function which prints the plot so no need to call print like `plot.eff`.

Comment: Adding print() makes last plot to appear but still it does not make all effect plots in one window.